# Discord.js ban command - role restricted

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

I have this code but I have to add a line that will allow to use it only for people with some role, for example with role "Moderator"
Because like this normal members can ban other members.

Can you help me please?

Or it can be usable only in some channel defined by ID

```
module.exports = {
    name: "ban",
    category: "moderation",
    description: "bans the member",
    usage: "<id | mention>",
    run: async (client, message, args) => {
        const logChannel = message.guild.channels.find(c => c.name === "logs") || message.channel;

        if (message.deletable) message.delete();

        // No args
        if (!args[0]) {
            return message.reply("Please provide a person to ban.")
                .then(m => m.delete(5000));
        }

        if (!message.member.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")) {
            return message.reply("❌ You do not have permissions to ban members. Please contact a staff member")
                .then(m => m.delete(5000));

        }

        const toBan = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.get(args[0]);
        }

        if (!toBan.bannable) {
            return message.reply("I can't ban that person due to role hierarchy, I suppose.")
                .then(m => m.delete(5000));
        }


        await message.channel.send(promptEmbed).then(async msg => {
            // Await the reactions and the reactioncollector
            const emoji = await promptMessage(msg, message.author, 30, ["✅", "❌"]);

            if (emoji === "✅") {
                msg.delete();

                toBan.ban(args.slice(1).join(" "))
                    .catch(err => {
                        if (err) return message.channel.send(`didn't work`)
                    });

                logChannel.send(embed);
            } else if (emoji === "❌") {
                msg.delete();

                message.reply(`ban canceled.`)
                    .then(m => m.delete(10000));
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your code uses Discord permissions to detect if a member has ban permissions. If you want to check this via a role, remove the actual system (those lines:

```js
if (!message.member.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")) {
    return message.reply("❌ You do not have permissions to ban members. Please contact a staff member")
    .then(m => m.delete(5000));
}
```

) and add this instead:

```js
if (!message.member.roles.some((r) => r.name === "Moderator") {
    return message.reply("❌ You do not have permissions to ban members. Please contact a staff member")
    .then(m => m.delete(5000));
}
```

This will return an error message if the member doesn't have the Moderator role.